# Am I missing anything for my constructor for Evil Hangman?

Tags: c++

Here's the header file.

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class FamilySet
{
public:
    FamilySet();
    // Default

    FamilySet(string file);
    // Initializes from a word file

    FamilySet(string file, int len);
    // Initializes from a word file where the word
    // must be of length len.

    ~FamilySet();

private:
    vector<string> masterList;
    // This stores all words currently "valid"

    unordered_map<string, vector<string>> dictionaries;
    // Stores a dictionary for each family. Each word from
    // the masterList is contained within one of these
    // these vector dictionaries.

    int iterCount;    // Used for iterator
};
```

here's what i have for my constructor. this constructor will be the only one of relevance. I have an idea that i need to initialize the vector and unordered map but not too sure how.

```
FamilySet::FamilySet(string file, int len) {
     iterCount = 0;
     ifstream myFile(file);
     string word;
     while(myFile >> word)
     {
         masterList.push_back(word);
     }

     myFile.close(); 
}
```

Comment: Please expand on the purpose and intended contents of `dictionaries`

Comment: Dictionaries will use a string as a key and the words in the dictionary as the info. I'll add more information to the question.

Comment: Better to initialize `iterCount` in the class like `int iterCount{};`, which will initialize it to its zero value, instead of doing it in each constructor.

Comment: You don't use the parameter `len`

Comment: `string file, int len` should be `const string file, const int len` most likely.

Comment: Wouldn't you know if it was missing something or not if you compiled it and tried running it? What happens when you do? Compile with all hints and warnings enabled.

Comment: You don't need to initialize the vector and unordered map. Just start adding elements as you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have seen so far what you would want to do before you start with the while loop is to check if the file has opened properly.

You will probably also want to place your iterCount variable inside your while loop.

Also if you do decide to use len, then you can incorporate it in your while loop as a boundary condititon in order to be able to read only a specific amount of words.

```
FamilySet::FamilySet(string file, int len) {
     iterCount = 0;
     ifstream myFile(file);
     if(myFile.fail())
     {
         cout << "File failed to open\n";
     }

     string word;
     // this way you will only read a len amount of words if this is what you want
     while(myFile >> word && len--)
     {
         ++iterCount;
         masterList.push_back(word);
     }

     myFile.close(); }
```